# @ symbol in front of a file name

Tags: batch-file, makefile, nmake

I have a makefile (intended for nmake) with the following contents.

```
w = \
abort_.obj \
backspac.obj \
c_abs.obj \
c_cos.obj \
c_div.obj \
c_exp.obj \
c_log.obj \
c_sin.obj \
c_sqrt.obj \
cabs.obj \
close.obj \
d_abs.obj \
d_acos.obj \
d_asin.obj \
d_atan.obj \
d_atn2.obj \
d_cnjg.obj \
d_cos.obj \
d_cosh.obj \
d_dim.obj \
d_exp.obj \
d_imag.obj \
d_int.obj \
d_lg10.obj \
d_log.obj \
d_mod.obj \
d_nint.obj \
d_prod.obj \
d_sign.obj \
d_sin.obj \
d_sinh.obj \
d_sqrt.obj \
d_tan.obj \
d_tanh.obj \
derf_.obj \
derfc_.obj \
dfe.obj \
dolio.obj \
dtime_.obj \
due.obj \
ef1asc_.obj \
ef1cmc_.obj \
endfile.obj \
erf_.obj \
erfc_.obj \
err.obj \
etime_.obj \
exit_.obj \
f77_aloc.obj \
f77vers.obj \
fmt.obj \
fmtlib.obj \
ftell_.obj \
getarg_.obj \
getenv_.obj \
h_abs.obj \
h_dim.obj \
h_dnnt.obj \
h_indx.obj \
h_len.obj \
h_mod.obj \
h_nint.obj \
h_sign.obj \
hl_ge.obj \
hl_gt.obj \
hl_le.obj \
hl_lt.obj \
i77vers.obj \
i_abs.obj \
i_dim.obj \
i_dnnt.obj \
i_indx.obj \
i_len.obj \
i_mod.obj \
i_nint.obj \
i_sign.obj \
iargc_.obj \
iio.obj \
ilnw.obj \
inquire.obj \
l_ge.obj \
l_gt.obj \
l_le.obj \
l_lt.obj \
lbitbits.obj \
lbitshft.obj \
lread.obj \
lwrite.obj \
main.obj \
open.obj \
pow_ci.obj \
pow_dd.obj \
pow_di.obj \
pow_hh.obj \
pow_ii.obj \
pow_ri.obj \
pow_zi.obj \
pow_zz.obj \
r_abs.obj \
r_acos.obj \
r_asin.obj \
r_atan.obj \
r_atn2.obj \
r_cnjg.obj \
r_cos.obj \
r_cosh.obj \
r_dim.obj \
r_exp.obj \
r_imag.obj \
r_int.obj \
r_lg10.obj \
r_log.obj \
r_mod.obj \
r_nint.obj \
r_sign.obj \
r_sin.obj \
r_sinh.obj \
r_sqrt.obj \
r_tan.obj \
r_tanh.obj \
rdfmt.obj \
rewind.obj \
rsfe.obj \
rsli.obj \
rsne.obj \
s_cat.obj \
s_cmp.obj \
s_copy.obj \
s_paus.obj \
s_rnge.obj \
s_stop.obj \
sfe.obj \
sig_die.obj \
signal_.obj \
sue.obj \
system_.obj \
typesize.obj \
uio.obj \
uninit.obj \
util.obj \
wref.obj \
wrtfmt.obj \
wsfe.obj \
wsle.obj \
wsne.obj \
xwsne.obj \
z_abs.obj \
z_cos.obj \
z_div.obj \
z_exp.obj \
z_log.obj \
z_sin.obj \
z_sqrt.obj
```

-----------snip----------------------------

```
vcf2c.lib: $w
    lib -out:vcf2c.lib @libf2c.lbc
```

What does the @ in front of, "libf2c.lbc," do?  In a batch file @ suppresses output but I don't see how that applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's a LIB command file.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h34w59b3.aspx) As described on the page I linked:

> You can pass command-line arguments to LIB in a command file using the
>   following syntax:
>
> `LIB @commandfile`
>
> The file commandfile is a text file. No space or tab is allowed
>   between the at sign (@) and the file name. There is no default
>   extension; you must specify the full file name, including any
>   extension. Wildcards cannot be used. You can specify an absolute or
>   relative path with the file name.
>
> In the command file, arguments can be separated by spaces or tabs, as
>   they can on the command line; they can also be separated by newline
>   characters. Use a semicolon (;) to mark a comment. LIB ignores all
>   text from the semicolon to the end of the line.
>
> You can specify either all or part of the command line in a command
>   file, and you can use more than one command file in a LIB command. LIB
>   accepts the command-file input as if it were specified in that
>   location on the command line. Command files cannot be nested. LIB
>   echoes the contents of command files unless the /NOLOGO option is
>   used.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common convention on some systems (but not universally supported on any system) that a filename preceded by an `@` means that the program should read the contents of the file and interpret the contents as arguments to the program.

So in your case, the `lib` program will read in the file `libf2c.lbc` and use its contents as arguments.

I guess it's possible that this is a feature of `nmake`, I don't know much about `nmake`.  It's certainly not part of any "traditional" make program.